# PHP/MySQL - Update Database/Run PHP Script on Button Click

Tags: php, html, mysql, button

I have a 'registration' page in PHP and I would like the script to run when an HTML button is clicked.

The PHP basically checks if all fields are filled, checks if the password and email confirmations are the same and saves to the database.

This is the code:

```
<?php
$Name = isset($_POST['Name']);
$Surname = isset($_POST['Surname']);

$Username = isset($_POST['Username']);

$Email = isset($_POST['Email']);
$C_Email = isset($_POST['C_Email']);

$Password = isset($_POST['password']);
$C_Password = isset($_POST['c_password']);

$SecQ = isset($_POST['SecQ']);
$SecA = isset($_POST['SecA']);


$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin', 'storefile1234');
mysql_select_db ("storefile");

$check_username = mysql_query("SELECT FROM users WHERE username = '$Username'");
$check_email = mysql_query("SELECT FROM users WHERE Email = '$Email'");


if (!$con)
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

if ($Name == null || $Surname== null || $Username == null || $Password == null || $C_Password == null || $Email == null || $C_Email == null || $SecQ == null || $SecA == null ) {

    echo "Missing details. Please enter all fields.";


} else {

    if(mysql_num_rows($check_username) != 0 && mysql_num_rows($check_email) != 0)
            {
            echo "Username/Email already exists";
            }
            if  ($Email == $C_Email && $Password == $C_Password) {

                $query = "INSERT INTO users (Username, Name,Surname, Password, Email, SecQ, SecA) VALUES ('NULL', ".$Username."', ".$Name."', ".$Surname."', ".$Password."', ".$SecQ."', ".$SecA."', ".$Email.')"';

                mysql_query($query) or die ('Error registering.');

                echo "Greetings, ".$Name.", you have been registered. ";

    }  else {

        echo "Error registering your account. Please try again.";
            }

 }


?>
```

Also, is it recommended?

Whenever I run this page `Missing details. Please enter all fields.` displays, without having entered any details.

How do you do this?

Comment: offtopic: dont use `mysql_*` functions. Beter look on **`PDO`** with prepared statesments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the issue of printing that message when you first load the page, use the array_key_exists function to test if the user has already submited something before checking if any field is null. Something like this:

```
if (array_key_exists('Name', $_POST) || array_key_exists('Surname', $_POST) || ... ) 
    if ($Name == null || $Surname== null || ... ) 
        echo "Missing details. Please enter all fields.";
```

Observation: you cannot use the isset function for the same purpose since, according to php documentation, it "determine if a variable is set **and is not NULL**"

Comment: that seemed to work, however, XAMPP is somehow forbidding me from accessing the DB, givinig me this error `Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. Error 403` The host, username and pass are correct for thr DB.

Answer (score 2):

You tying to get values by `isset($_POST['Username']);` and like this functions...
But [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) says: `Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.`

So check on `true`, nut `null`. And escape your POST data after.

You can do like this:

```
$Name = isset($_POST['Name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Name']) : null;
```

P.S. Please again. Do not use `mysql_*` function. They are **DEPRECATED**.
Look on **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)** (or `mysqli_*)`

Comment: The check would not solve his problem because he is reusing the variables he assigns the return of `isset` to in his sql statement.

Comment: @Stranger So basically I need to fix the `isset()` functions and it will work on button click?

Comment: @Brian Yes. You can just check if they exist or not (true|false), but you dont get value of them. Benjamin answer isnt good enough, but solevs problem.

Answer (score 0):

You misuse `isset`

Try something like this:

```
$Name = null;
if (isset($_POST['Name'])) {
    $Name = $_POST['Name'];
}
```

`isset` is only to check if a value is set.

Comment: So you need to use that function for each variable ?

Comment: And dont forget to **ESCAPE** post data!